# Latex/VIM : change all $$ .. $$ to \begin{equation} .... \end{equation}

Tags: vim, latex, vim-plugin, pdflatex

I received a 100 page Latex document with all equations between `$$...$$` and I need to change them all to `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`

Is there some clever way to do this in Latex (some built in functionality) or in Vim?

In Vim I am thinking

Either: a way to replace `abc` with `dbf` where all letters stand for patterns.

Or: replace all `$$` with `\begin{equation}`, then replace every second `\begin{equation}` with `\end{equation}`

I'm not sure how to accomplish either though.

Comment: Is there only 1 equation per line, with no equations spanning multiple lines? If not, rkta's solution is probably your best bet.

Comment: @rkta I know how to use a macro, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:%s/\$\$\(\_.\{-}\)\$\$/\\begin{equation}\1\\end{equation}/g
```

It searches `$$` followed by everything (`.`) including newline (`\_`), non greedy (`\{-}`), followed by another `$$`. On the right part, `\1` means "put the backreference" number 1, i.e. the first `\(...\)` on the left.

This works with equations on single or multiple lines.

Comment: I already used the macro suggestion. However this was the answer I was searching for, for future use and all. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Vim:**

Use a recording(`:help q`), e.g. `qe`:

- go to the first `$$` you want to change
- replace with `\begin{equation}`
- search for the next `$$`
- replace with `\end{equation}`
- search for next `$$`
- stop recording

Reapply recording with `@`, `@e` in my example.
`@` takes a count, see `:help @`